# python ** vs math.pow() regarding negative values

Tags: python

```
from math import pow

assert pow(-3, 2) == 9
assert -3 ** 2 == -9
```

why are the two above assertions valid?

in regular math, when a negative numbered is powered to 2, it becomes positive. which one of these is equal to the regular math I know?
is ignoring negative value the only difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the order in which the operations are performed. In the first case, `pow(-3,2)` takes as inputs a `-3` as first input and a `2` as the second input. In the second case, the `**` has precedence over the `-`, so the order in which the operations are executed is

1. Calculate `3**2`
2. Change the sign of the result

This leads to the result being `-9`.

Answer (score -1):

Because python calculate the minus after it calculate the power.

```
In [2]: -3**2
Out[2]: -9

In [3]: (-3)**2
Out[3]: 9
```